# PHPExcel don't read my XLS-file

Tags: php, phpexcel, xls

I have a XLS-File and I want to read out the values out of it.

I use PHPExcel, but I'm new to it.

This is my PHP-script

```
set_time_limit(0);    
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

if (!file_exists("08102013_123230.xls")) 
{
    die("There's no Excel file to read from");
}

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("08102013_123230.xls");    
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel -> getActiveSheet();     

$test = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,5)->getValue();
echo "The value is :".$test;  


echo "<br/><br/>End".time();   
?>
```

**This is how my Excel-File looks like:**

[image]

I tried to read out from a very simple excel-sheet and then it worked. So what can be the error?

Maybe the file-type is not a xls-file or ...

Thank for helping!

Comment: What does a call to PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify() return? What filetype does MS Excel default to if you do a "Save As"? What actually happens when you load the file in PHPExcel? Do you get any errors (on screen or in server logs)? Is anything loaded? PHPExcel throws exceptions, so add a try/catch block around your load to catch any exceptions and check for any errors.

Comment: I had changed my Excel-options one day before to ,,Save as CSV" ... :( ... Now the File-type is ,,Excel5" and I can access the data!